# How to mass edit and replace MySQL database row, replacing all using a list?

Tags: mysql

So I have this list of 230 countries already in my database table called "countrylist" inside the "country" row. besides the "country" row, I also have the "code" row, which has the country code of that country in it.

The countries are in English and since I need the country names in 3 other languages as well, I duplicated the table for the 3 other languages too. I also programmed the PHP code to choose the right table based on the language.

I have the list of the country names in the other 3 languages ready and they have the same ordering.

BUT... this leaves me with 230 countries to replace in 3 languages, and that's a lot of wasted time for something which I already know should be much simpler than basic copy pasting. Although I don't even have a slight clue of how or if this can be done...

I want to know if there is a way to preserve the "code" row in the tables and replace all of the countries in the "country" row with a query/command?

Thanks, any help is much appreciated

Comment: What does your list look like? Can you include a few rows in your post? Also, what is the structure of your country tables?

Comment: why not one table a col for each language?

Comment: So many other better ways to go about this. @Dagon method is a really good way.

Comment: I agree. I'm hoping to see more. It could also be one table with one row per country per language, in case other languages come into play.

Comment: @EdGibbs my list is in Notepad and has one country per line (230 lines in total). Structure sample: code - country - zone - list. and entry sample: DE - Germany  - 1  - 1

Comment: @Dagon I'm really not good at databases, just basic knowledge. could you explain more please?

Comment: Claudio - I'd recommend following up with the @FreshPrinceOfSO suggestion and asking about making this more relational. As for loading for a text file, take a look at the [MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). If you need a basic example, look [here](http://jameshd.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/mysql-load-data-infile-examples/). This one uses `;` as a delimiter so you'll have to substitute `-` or maybe ` - ` (space dash space) for the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers were practical due to the nature of the code from before, so I had to redo everything manually with Dreamweaver copy and replace. Took an hour but it was done right.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO countries_fr (code) SELECT countries_en.code FROM countries_en
```

Assuming you have the tables countries_fr and countries_en, and both have the `code` column.
This will insert all the `code` from the countries_en table into the code of countries_fr table.

Comment: I know others have been helping too, but this is the most helpful answer so far. How about mass replacing all entries in the "country" field?

Comment: Wouldn't this create a whole new set of records since you're doing an insert instead of an update?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Yes it will create new records in a different table, but that's just what he's asking for, isn't it?

Comment: @Arnelle Balane After rereading the original question I'm not it's making any sense anyhow. If the OP duplicated the tables and then altered the language of the country, then it sounds like they could do a cross table query.

Comment: @Arnelle Balane I thought they were saying they wanted to keep the code in the tables, but update the country names in the duplicate tables.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Well it's just a misinterpretation, then :)

Comment: @ClaudioDelgado For mass updating, if you want all the records to have the same value you can have `UPDATE countries_fr SET country = new_value` (this will set all the records' country field to `new_value`). If you want to mass update using values from another table: `UPDATE countries_fr SET country = (SELECT countries_en.country FROM countries_en WHERE countries_en.code = countries_fr.code)`. But I'm guessing that the new values that you want to update the records with are not yet on a database table? If so, I guess a mass update isn't possible and you'll need to update each record one by one

Answer (score 0):

You create a *relational* model.

```
country (id, name)
countryLang (countryId, lang, translatedName)
```

This way, the languages are independent of your parent country name.

```
| ID |   NAME | COUNTRYID | LANG | TRANSLATEDNAME |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 | Poland |         1 |   en |         Poland |
|  1 | Poland |         1 |   pl |         Polska |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caec4/1)

Answer (score 0):

So it's normalized, you have to add columns for the other 3 names in the table, so (replace the languages with those desired):

```
alter table countries add french varchar(45),spanish varchar(45),russian varchar(45);
```

Since the code is exactly the same you can use it like a key field this one time.

```
update countries c set c.french=(select country from french where french.code = countries.code),
c.spanish=(select country from spanish where spanish.code = countries.code),
c.russian=(select country from russian where russian.code = countries.code);
```

**On the other hand...**

If you were to simply replace the country name you would have to maintain 4 sets of code.

```
update countries set country=(select country from language2 where language2.code=countries.code);
```